# Multiplication of generalized functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

I would like to know if there is any associative algebra $( A(\mathbb{R}), +, \cdot )$ such that:

EDIT:  Fan Zheng found an inconsistency in my requirements. Therefore I changed the function space in point 4. I hope that it is more consistent now.

1. The space $L^1( \mathbb{R} )$ is linearly embedded into $A(\mathbb{R}) $
2. There is antisymmetric (differentiation) operator $\partial$ on $A(\mathbb{R})$ which satisfies the Leibnitz rule.
3. The restriction of $\partial$ to $ C^1(\mathbb{R})$ fucntions coincides with the usual derivative.
4. For all functions $ f,g \in L^2(\mathbb{R}) \cap L^1(\mathbb{R})$ the product $ f \cdot g = h $ is given by $ h(x) = f(x) g(x) $

If this is not possible, I would like to know, if there if a possibility to obtain such algebra if I lower requirements 3 and 4 to

3. The restriction of $\partial$ to $ C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ fucntions coincides with the usual derivative
4. For all functions $ f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}) \cap L^1( \mathbb{R} )$ the square $ f \cdot f = h $ is given by $ h(x) = f(x)^2 $

Thank You in advance for Your ansvers.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colombeau_algebra

Comment: @Michael Renardy: I do not see why Colombeau algebras are what I want. I understood from the wikipedia page You linked that colombeau algebras satisfy the point 4 with all function belonging to $C^\infty ( \mathbb{R} )$ which is slightly different from what I desire. Or do You refer to the Schwartz's imposibility result explained at the page?

Comment: I realize Columbeau algebras do not address your specific question. But searching the literature on them might give you pointers to related efforts.

Comment: @Michael Renardy: Thank you for directions.

Comment: It may be stupid, but what prevents $A(\mathbb R)$ to be $L^1(\mathbb R)\oplus L^1(\mathbb R)$, where $L^1(\mathbb R)$ embeds as the first factor? Plus, where do $f$ and $g$ live in point 4? $L^2(\mathbb R)$ may be neither in $L^1(\mathbb R)$ nor $A(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: Sorry, $L^1(\mathbb R)$ should embed _diagonally_ in $L^1(\mathbb R)\oplus L^1(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: @Fan Zheng: I made an edit to address the inconsistency in point 4. I hope it is clear now. Thank You for Your idea, I will think about it. However I have no idea how to define the operator $\partial$ and multiplication over the space $L^1(\mathbb{R}) \oplus L^1(\mathbb{R})$ . Is there any canonical way to do it?

Comment: I guess you can define it componentwise, as if the functions are supported on two parallel lines. Also, it actually doesn't matter much if the embedding is targetting the first factor or diagonal, as we don't have to preserve units because there is no unit anyway. For a simpler example, I think you can direct sum $L^1(\mathbb R)$ with $L^1(\text{pt})=\mathbb R$.

Comment: @FanZheng: Still, there is no standard notion of a differential operator $\partial: L^1\to L^1$ as well there is no standard notion of multiplication $L^1\times L^1 \to L^1$.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the point completely...

Answer (score 2):

As far as I remember the Colombeau algebra is the best you can have which contains all distributions: Differentiation and multiplication remains the same only for $C^\infty$. 
See the following recent paper and references therein.

- MR2888443 Reviewed 
  Burtscher, Annegret(A-WIEN-DM); Kunzinger, Michael(A-WIEN-DM)
  Algebras of generalized functions with smooth parameter dependence. (English summary) 
  Proc. Edinb. Math. Soc. (2) 55 (2012), no. 1, 105–124.

Comment: Thank You for the ansver. Are there any options that do not contain all distributions?